# Simple while loop, that appends user input into a list ; not working

Tags: python, input, while-loop

I'm trying to write a simple code that takes a user input and appends whatever number user typed in into a list. Lastly when the user types "done", the loop stops.

```
a = []
user_input = input("Please enter a number: ")
while user_input:
    if user_input == "done":
        break
    int(user_input)
    a.append(user_input)
print(a)
```

But for some reason when I type done, the loop doesn't stop and the list does not get printed.

Comment: The variable `user_input` never changes in the loop, why would the loop end? Maybe you should put the `input()` inside the loop?

Answer (score 1):

Put the `input()` inside the loop like so:

```
a = []
while True:
    user_input = input("Please enter a number: ")
    if user_input == "done":
        break
    user_input = int(user_input)
    a.append(user_input)
print(a)
```

Comment: It still seems it doesn't print out the list.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking the indentation then and make sure that everything is indented correctly.
I just  copied your code here : https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/
and it printed out the list .
The print statement needs to have the same “level of indentation” as the “while true “ statement

Answer (score 0):

The `user_input` never changes inside the loop, so it will never terminate. You need to put the `input` call inside the loop.

If the list still doesn't get printed (as you seemed to indicate on another answer), the problem is somewhere else. It could possibly be a problem with the interpreter/terminal, since from your question it seems you are able to input more data even though the loop should prevent you from doing that.